# Eclipse Debugging - Stopping without a breakpoint

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

I am debugging some Java code with Eclipse 3.4.2. I have disabled all the breakpoints, yet the debugger still stops at a specific line. This point is several lines before a `null pointer exception` is triggered. Curiously, when I run the same code/run configuration, but not in the debugger, the null pointer exception does not occur.

Also, if I step through this code from the beginning of the method causing the `null pointer exception`, using the exact same input, there is no problem. It only occurs when I remove all breakpoints but Eclipse decides to stop there regardless.

Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 45):

I had the same problem and finally found the following configuration option:
Windows -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug -> Suspend execution on uncaught exceptions
I unchecked it, and the problem disappeared.
However, may be it's good to know about uncaught exceptions. I just disabled it because the problem was in Spring framework, not in my code, and hence I could correct nothing...
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I was having the exact same problem but your answer has worked for me.

Comment: after about 10 years this still works for me

Answer (score 18):

Eclipse also supports exception break points (which stop your program when a certain exception is thrown). You can see them in the "Breakpoints" panel of the debugger. In your case, this could be a ClassCastException, for example.

If that panel is empty, then it can be a bug in your Java VM or maybe you have two processes open in the debugger. If all else fails, try to debug it in Eclipse 3.5.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was my case

Answer (score 4):

I've encountered this as well and have yet to find a satisfactory answer. Try doing a workspace refresh, full rebuild and restart Eclipse.

At least one of those suggestions will help.

Failing that - rebuild or restore your workspace (I always keep a backup)

Comment: I deleted my workspace and it worked, hope it doesn't comeback

Comment: Also try Run->Remove All Breakpoints as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7178096/eclipse-stops-at-non-existent-breakpoint