# eclipse stop unintended debug

Tags: eclipse, debugging, tomcat, servlets

I have a tomcat servlet project, which is normally running in eclipse, except of one line, which always stops the debugger without of a breakpoint. If I manually proceed debugging by pressing 2resume", all will work fine.
Is there any directive/annotation to prevent stopping the debugger on lines without breakpoints?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1668944/eclipse-debugging-stopping-without-a-breakpoint

Answer (score 1):

Clean and build ur project...i have faced similar issues...it got resolved after a full clean and build was done.

Comment: I cleaned the project, without of any effect on this issue

Comment: I had to "Remove All Breakpoints"... There was definitely no breakpoint visible.

I have no idea, where such "ghost breakpoints" come from...